# What is the use of the courier in Dota Auto Chess?

Tags: dota-autochess

In Dota Auto Chess, you have a courier, that can just move around the board.

It doesn't attack, it doesn't interact with the fight in any way. So what is the point of the courier?

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: I have edited your question to only ask about one game. If you would rather ask about Teamfight Tactics, feel free to edit this question again, as long as you don't ask about two unrelated games in the same question.

Comment: Was asking for both games at the same time because both games are very similar, and have that same mechanic.

Comment: For clarification, you mean Dota Auto Chess as a custom game mode, and not Dota Underlords, that is the standalone Auto Chess, right?

Comment: Well the direction I was going was the gamemode, but if it does seemingly nothing in underlords too, it could apply (was originally asking for TFT too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In dota autochess, courier can collect items, put items on board and combine items. Other than that, rest is purely cosmetic. If you collect enough candies by playing and be on top 3, you can change the look of the courier.